# Command line partition info

Tags: command-line, partitioning, uuid

I'm looking for the name of a command like blkid but shows the data in sort of a tree from the command line. I saw it here on askubuntu and ran it, but I must have had a space before the command and it isn't in the history. If anyone knows the name it would really help my sanity.

Comment: df -h, fdisk -l, parted ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lsblk` lists your block devices in a tree.

Comment: nice one, noted

Comment: Thank You!! You don't realize how much forgetting something like that can eat away at me!